# Have the lyrics of Ace Combat Zero's soundtrack "Zero" been translated?

Tags: ace-combat

I've been listening to it for quite a long time, and always wondered what the lyrics are translated to.

I do see some draw comparisons to Ace Combat 5's soundtrack "The Unsung War".

Comment: https://acecombat.fandom.com/wiki/The_Unsung_War

Comment: https://acecombat.fandom.com/wiki/Zero_(song)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my literal translation. I suspect either a transcription or translation error in some places (or poetic elision), and have put what I think it should be in brackets.

Note that I have no idea of the context. I assume this makes sense given the plot of the game? The he/she probably refers to Razgriz, but may refer to the unnamed source of the power.

*fundet* appears twice. The first time makes more sense as a figurative "forges", but the second time may be a literal "pours out". Keeping the same word both times maintains the stylistic echo.

> With her power
> She will forge a demon
> I [who/she] will break death:
>
> Then he/she will die.
> With sleep finished,
> Razgriz will rise again:
>
> With history changes [changing] greatly
> Razgriz reveals himself:
> At first the demon is wicked.
>
> Glory changes [him] greatly
> [and] Razgriz reveals himself:
> Her demon forges death
>
> Glory changes [him] greatly
> [and] Razgriz reveals himself:
> He will die (with sleep finished)
>
> Razgriz will rise again:
> Great...
> He is a great hero.

Answer (score 2):

The Ace Combat Wiki lists [the lyrics](https://acecombat.fandom.com/wiki/Zero_(song)) as follows

> Cum potentia sua
> Daemon fundet
> Mortem interam:
>
> Deinde moritur.
> Cum somnus finit,
> Razgriz surget iterum:
>
> Cum historia mutat valde
> Razgriz revelat ipsum:
> Primum daemon scelestus est.
>
> Gloria mutat valde
> Razgriz revelat ipsum:
> Sua daemon fundet mortem
>
> Gloria mutat valde
> Razgriz revelat ipsum:
> Moritur (Cum somnus finit)
>
> Razgriz surget iterum:
> Magnus
> Magnus heros est.

Which translates (via Google Translate) as

> With his power
> He casts the devil
> Total death:
>
> Then he dies.
> When sleep ends
> Razgriz rises again:
>
> When history changes a lot
> Razgriz reveals himself:
> The first demon is a criminal.
>
> Glory changes a lot
> Razgriz reveals himself:
> His own demon casts death
>
> Glory changes a lot
> Razgriz reveals himself:
> Dies (When Sleep Ends)
>
> Razgriz rises again:
> Big
> He is a great hero.

Comment: I'm sure someone will be along to correct my appalling Latin shortly.

Comment: Google Translate is pretty bad at Latin, yeah.

Comment: @OrangeDog - What's Latin for *errare humanum est*?

Comment: I don't like translating "Primum daemon scelestus est" as "The first demon is a criminal". Isn't it more like "First as an evil demon"?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez perhaps, with some poetic license. Literally it's "first demon is wicked".

Comment: @OrangeDog You wouldn't translate "primum" as an adverb ("firstly')? But we agree that "criminal" is not a good choice ;)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez you could do, then it's "at first the demon is wicked". I guess that makes sense with all the _mutat_ that then happens.